# breezejs enum as an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

In my model, I have an enum called `EventCategory` and also an entity called `Event`. The enum definition looks something like this.

```
public enum EventCategory
{
    Convension,
    Meeting,
    ProductRelease
}
```

in the entity `Event`, it has a field called `EventCategory`. I want to put those two things in nested dropdowns, so that `EventCategory` which is the enum is in the first dropdown and the second dropdown which will be the `Event` entity which will be filtered based on the selection on the first dropdown.

if I do it just using `jQuery ajax` and `knockoutjs`, I would first retrieve the `EventCategory` enum values and put it in the first dropdown and in the knockout viewmodel, subscribe to the selectedEventCategory and fetch the Events in there.

But, is there a better way of doing this in breezejs?

any help really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We have been considering adding additional metadata to the Breeze MetadataStore regarding .NET enums but have not yet clarified the design.  Please vote for [Breeze metadata for Enums](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3851540-retrieve-values-of-an-enum-server-side-to-be-able-) on the Breeze User Voice.  We take these suggestions very seriously.